# How to Add Multiple tags/strings to rel="value"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am using a fancybox gallery template.  When you click on a nav element in the header, thumbnails that match the rel="value" light up.  How can I make the same thumbnail light up for multiple tags?  Basically, something like: rel="value1 value2"  The code that I have listed below is not working.  Any element that has more than one value for rel="" lights up whenever any nav button is pushed.  What should I do?  I appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<!-- .nav -->
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="produce">Producing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="design">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="puppet">Puppetry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="multimedia">Multimedia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- /.nav -->
</div>
<!-- content -->
<div id="content">
    <!-- .thumbs -->
    <ul class="thumbs">
    <li class="first"><a href="images/images/h-slide4.jpg" rel="empty"><img src="images/images/h-thumb4.jpg" alt="description" /></a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="images/images/standin-slide1.jpg" rel="produce"><img src="images/images/sus-thumb7.jpg" alt="description" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/images/sus-slide1.jpg" rel="produce puppet"><img src="images/images/sus-thumb1.jpg" alt="description" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/images/sus-slide2.jpg" rel="puppet design"><img src="images/images/sus-thumb2.jpg" alt="description" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/images/sus-slide4.jpg" rel="multimedia"><img src="images/images/sus-thumb4.jpg" alt="description" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/images/sus-slide6.jpg" rel="produce multimedia puppet"><img src="images/images/sus-thumb6.jpg" alt="description" /></a></li>
    <li></li>
```

***For the first list element, where rel="empty" I do not want that thumbnail to light up ever.  I tried leaving rel="", but then the thumbnail lit up on any click.  The other list elements show examples of my attempts at multiple tags.

gallery.js:

```
$(".nav li a.produce").click(function(){

$("ul.thumbs").find("span").hide();
$(".nav li a").removeClass("current");
$("ul.thumbs a").css("opacity", "1");
$(this).addClass("current");
$("ul.thumbs a[rel=design], ul.thumbs a[rel=puppet], ul.thumbs a[rel=multimedia]").animate({opacity: ".2"}, "slow").parent().append("<span></span>");
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Could you clarify what's going on here? So when you click the produce link, it `$("ul.thumbs a").css("opacity", "1");` shows all the images. Then `$("ul.thumbs a[rel=design], ul.thumbs a[rel=puppet], ul.thumbs a[rel=multimedia]").animate({opacity: ".2"}, "slow").parent().append("<span></span>");` hides the images that aren't produce? Does this work with 1 tag instead of multiple?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you are using `rel` for this.  Using the `class` attribute seems like it would be a better match.  Is there a reason why you need to use `rel`?  I am not sure that the way you are using it is even valid.

If you use class instead, you can add multiples in the same way that you mentioned (`class = "puppet design"` would work).

Comment: I was using rel because that is the way the template was set up when I got it.  If I change to class, do I leave everything in the gallery.js the same, just changing that last line to: 

    $("ul.thumbs a[class=design], ul.thumbs a[class=puppet], ul.thumbs a[class=multimedia]").animate({opacity: ".2"}, "slow").parent().append("<span></span>");
        return false;
    });

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you could leave it the same, but if I were doing that, I would do `$("ul.thumbs a.design, ul.thumbs a.puppet, ul.thumbs a.multimedia").animate({opacity: ".2"}, "slow").parent().append("<span></span>"); return false;});` instead.  I think it is up to preference and I am not sure if there is an advantage to the way they did it.  I also haven't checked that the code is correct and runs.  I think you could leave it the same - try it and see!

Answer (score 1):

@Chrissi is right (+1). You should rather use *classes* instead so you can compare what *classes* from the `content` matches with the `class` of the selected `nav` item.

You basically need two functions :

the first one :

- catches the click on `nav` items
- validates what *classes* match from the `content`
- sets the `rel` attribute to those items so they will belong to the same gallery selected by the `nav` item

... so :

```
$('.nav a').on("click", function() {
    var className = $(this).attr("class"); // get class name of nav item
    var thisClass = "." + className; // builds a class selector from class name
    // get content items that matches the selector class and set the same rel attribute
    $(".thumbs a").filter(thisClass).attr({
        "rel": className,
        "title": className // optional
    }).first().trigger("click"); // fires gallery from first item
}); // on
```

the second one :

- binds all selectors from content to fancybox
- filters the `class="empty"` so it doesn't open in fancybox (does nothing)
- removes the attribute `rel` (set by the first function) after close

... so :

```
$(".thumbs a").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        if ($(this.element).hasClass("empty")) {
            return false; // ignores item with class="empty"
        }
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        $(this.element).removeAttr("rel title"); // remove rel after close
    }
});​
```

since the last function binds all content's items to fancybox, they will be opened in fancybox out of any gallery if they are clicked individually, except that with `class="empty"`

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N38xj/)**

**NOTES** :

- `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+
- this demo uses fancybox v2.1.3+